# PHP: How to get values from array using clause?

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all I have an array

```
$data = array("https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-pXObolgHAdo/UbBLHGz1R6I/AAAAAAAAAbg/aAkGHbXQ6WU/w958-h715-no/111.jpg",
          "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-F_ngXcmSdxY/UbBLypozWvI/AAAAAAAAAew/juDGaqNUiSc/w958-h715-no/411.jpg",
          "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dxOkxkoZd0k/Ua3jQFu2WqI/AAAAAAAAAQc/eYX-u6mtF3k/w958-h715-no/113.jpg",
          "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8XTn3y4s8IY/Ua3jTOTRmxI/AAAAAAAAAQw/6qQA7xtagEo/w958-h715-no/121.jpg");
```

How can I get specific data from the array using a clause?

eg. I want to pull a data from the array with 121.jpg.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: What do you mean by "clause"? I can't think of a standard meaning of that word that would be relevant, so you might want to expand on what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop the array and check the value:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each ($data)) {
    if(strpos($value, '121.jpg') !== false)
    {
        var_dump($value);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Beware `strpos()` will return `0` if it finds the result at the beginning of the string, so you need to be careful using it in an if statement. i've edited your answer to handle that situation properly. :-)

Comment: re preg_grep(), I'm pretty sure that will actually be slower and you need to be careful with characters like ".", so I personally wouldn't use preg_grep unless you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

May be you mean [Closure](https://www.php.net/closure) ? What if there are multiple images with the same name ?

```
function get_image_url($name, array $images) {
    $image_url = array_filter($images, function($value) use ($name) {
        return (preg_replace('/^(.*\/)/', '', $value) == $name);
    });
    
    if (0 == sizeof($image_url)) {
        return false;
    } elseif (1 == sizeof($image_url)) {
        return reset($image_url);
    }
    
    return $image_url;
}
```

Example:

```
$images = array(
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-pXObolgHAdo/UbBLHGz1R6I/AAAAAAAAAbg/aAkGHbXQ6WU/w958-h715-no/111.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-F_ngXcmSdxY/UbBLypozWvI/AAAAAAAAAew/juDGaqNUiSc/w958-h715-no/411.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dxOkxkoZd0k/Ua3jQFu2WqI/AAAAAAAAAQc/eYX-u6mtF3k/w958-h715-no/113.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8XTn3y4s8IY/Ua3jTOTRmxI/AAAAAAAAAQw/6qQA7xtagEo/w958-h715-no/121.jpg",
        "121.jpg"
    );
    
    var_dump(get_image_url('111.jpg', $images));
    // string(103) "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-pXObolgHAdo/UbBLHGz1R6I/AAAAAAAAAbg/aAkGHbXQ6WU/w958-h715-no/111.jpg"
    
    var_dump(get_image_url('121.jpg', $images));
    // array(2) {
    //  [3] =>
    //  string(103) "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-8XTn3y4s8IY/Ua3jTOTRmxI/AAAAAAAAAQw/6qQA7xtagEo/w958-h715-no/121.jpg"
    //  [4] =>
    //  string(7) "121.jpg"
    // }
    
    var_dump(get_image_url('invalid.jpg', $images)); 
    // bool(false)
```